# Make some posts Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

There are some posts that don't really fit the Q/A format of Stack Exchange and because of this could be considered off-topic. I really don't want them to be closed (like in [this recent case](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1813/125)), that's why I've thought about converting them into ["Community Wiki"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) post?

Does anyone really understand how these wiki pages work, and if these questions fit that format better?

Here's some of these "Q/As" that I consider problematic:

- [Tutorials and Resources](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1824/125)
- [E-commerce solutions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/299/125)
- [Plugin wish list](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1813/125)

Comment: Done & done, thanks for the suggestion! After discussing with the other mods, we decided to convert "Tutorials and Resources" and "E-commerce solutions" into community wikis. We have decided against re-opening or converting "Plugin wish list" because it is a poor fit for the Stack Exchange purpose. While the first two plugins amount to "What are the best X resources?", the third question is simply "What do you desire?". For obvious reasons, this is not useful in resolving anyone's issues, nor is it an effective way to communicate with P&T or plugin developers about feature requests.